# Divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where divs are overlapping each other, even though they should appear below each other, I have no idea why this is happening.[image]

**Container**

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="box" style="float:right">
            <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="box" style="float:left">
            <p></p>
        </div>


            <div class="longContent topLongContent">
         <h2>Long Content</h2>
         <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="longContent">
         <h2>Long Content</h2>
         <p></p>
            </div>

            <div class="longContent">
         <h2>Long Content</h2>
         <p></p>
            </div>

  </div>
```

**Style Sheet**

```
  body{
background-image:url('sos.png');
color:#ecf0f1;
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
font-weight: 300;
   }

  .container{
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
  }


   .box{
width:49%;
background-color:#2c3e50;   
margin-top:5%;
   }

   .box p{
 padding: 2% 5% 3% 5%;
   }

   .box h2{
 font-weight:800;
 padding: 2% 5% 0% 3%;
    }

   .longContent{
     width:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#34495e;
 margin-top:2%;
    }

   .topLongContent{
 margin-top:16%;
   }

   .longContent p{
 padding: 2% 5% 3% 5%;
   }

   .longContent h2{
 font-weight:800;
 padding: 2% 5% 0% 3%;
   }

   .header{
 width:100%;
 background-color:#2c3e50;  

/*  Drop shadow Bottom */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 4px -6px black;
    }


    .header h1{
  font-size:2.5em;
  font-weight:900;
  padding: 1% 0% 1% 3%;
     }

     .callToAction{
   float:right;
   font-size:1.25em;
   margin:-2% 5% 0% 0%;
   color:#f39c12;
      }
```

I have even tried removing the `.topLongContent` but the content still over laps and acts as though the box divs are part of the `longContent` divs.

Comment: It's because two are floated and the rest are not. Use `clear:both` on the first non-floated div

Answer (score 8):

Try clearing the floats with `clear: both` on the `.longContent` elements.

Comment: I would have never have known how to have fixed that, didn't even know clear:both was a feature. Thanks guys, really appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer as the right one so that others can quickly see what worked in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `clear:both` for class `longContent`

Comment: Thanks :) Whish I could have accepted both answers since they were so quick.

Answer (score 1):

The .clear property may help you.

Links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear